# Docker image not running with https and tomcat

Tags: docker, https, dockerfile, tomcat9

I am trying to run docker image with https URL instead of just http. The app is deployed in tomcat and I have generated docker image of it. When I run tomcat on https URL, it works fine but when I build docker image and try to run the image, the URL is not working.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.35

COPY conf/my-release-key.keystore /usr/local/tomcat/conf/my-release-key.keystore
COPY conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
ADD webapps/placeholder-webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080 8445
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

**server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8445" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="conf/my-release-key.keystore" keystorePass="arcsight"
           clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3" sslProtocol="TLS">
    </Connector>
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8445" />
```

Output on running docker image:
[image]

I don't get any error on running docker image but I don't even see anything on accessing

- https://localhost:8445 URL.
  I get ***This site can't be reached error on browser***

Comment: Can you please add your `server.xml` as well?

Comment: There is only port 8080 exposed. The Https port needs to be exposed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose port 8445 in Dockerfile using `EXPOSE 8445` and run the container using `-p 8445:8445` to map local port 8445 to port 8445 running inside the container.

Your logs don't show that tomcat is aware that it needs to prepare a connector to run on port 8445. It must be using default server.xml configuration. You need to provide your server.xml to the container using something like following.

`COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/`

Comment: I applied your solution! But I still get the site can't be reached error :(

Comment: Could it be due to tomcat image that I am using ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable SSL in `server.xml` by adding the following code and then copy it in the container `COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/`

```
<!--
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->
```

And apart from this `EXPOSE 8443`, in the `Dockerfile` instead of `EXPOSE 8080`, and then hit your service on `https://localhost:8443`

Comment: SSL was already enabled! and I am using port 8445 which I had put under EXPOSE of dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The ports you are using, 8445 and 8009 should be opened with `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes I have exposed those two ports. I think it could be due to tomcat version that I am using in dockerfile